# Is there google extension to ask to edit before sending an http request?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been searching for an google chrome extension on the webstore that enables me to prevent every http request, ask me if I want to modify it and the finally send it. I couldn't find any extension that fit this requirements,  I'm even considering to develop my own. Does any one knows a solution for this?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb?hl=en

Comment: This is not possible in Chrome because it doesn't allow asynchronous blocking of requests in its webRequest API for extensions.